# Minimal Bash-like line editing is supporting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

I am in the process to install Ubuntu on a brand-new Dell Windows 10 desktop. When I tried to boot on a bootable Ubuntu Bionic USB stick created by Rufus, I got a bug:

"Minimal Bash-like line editing is supporting. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions".

May I ask how to take care of it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your installation media is viable. You may need to redownload the ISO or reflash the USB. If you want these steps to auto-validate I suggest using the BitTorrent link under "alternative downloads" and Etcher to flash.

Comment: @ML6634 - i had the same problem and i just re-downloaded the iso and then used balena etcher instead of rufus. i recommend to use this etcher <https://www.balena.io/etcher/> , **you can try first to use balena etcher to re-create the usb** and if its not working, then re-download the iso image and use balena etcher again.

Comment: Thank Nmath & @johncli for the help! When I ran a bootable USB stick created by balena.io/etcher, I got some message such as "5.8013941 Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e". On Boot Menu, it often showed I had 2 flash drives: USB1 - UEFI OS(SanDisk) & USB2 - UEFI OS(SanDisk), although I just had 1 flash drive inserted into computer each time. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 or 19.04 quite a few times respectively on the internal hard drive, w/ Windows 10 removed. Each time when I ran Ubuntu, it just crashed, except I started & logged in Ubuntu 20.04 successfully once. Any comments? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that Legacy mode is not available anymore on the newest Dell computers. I am not sure whether it matters. Has anybody installed Ubuntu successfully on a brand-new Dell desktop?

Comment: when I saw this screen all I did was type in 'exit' and hit enter... then I was able to bring up grub as normal.

Comment: I recommend deleting all partitions available https://askubuntu.com/questions/46462/how-do-i-erase-format-a-harddisk-from-a-live-cd and installing ubuntu again

Answer (score 1):

1. Hi i had an issues with installing ubuntu on my new dell computer to.
2. As we discussed on comments you can try to change the SATA settings on your bios.

- reboot your pc and press F12 to enter BIOS Menu.
- go to Settings>System Configuration>Sata Operation.
- try to change the SATA Operation to ACHI instead of RAID ON or Disabled.

3. that is what helped me out to successfully install the ubuntu on my new dell pc.

Comment: Thank @johncli for the comment. I went to Bios Setup>Advanced>SATA Operation, & chose AHCI (Not RAID On) for SATA Operation. Then I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 or 19.04 from a bootable USB stick created on Windows 10 or Ubuntu respectively. Unfortunately, the same issue stayed. My desktop is Alienware Aurora R10. Anyone has any further comments? Thanks!

Comment: So, anybody has any ideas about this? Thanks.